# How can I use switch statements to add two integers in Java

Tags: java

I want to use a switch case to add hours which returns to days when the sum is 24

I have tried:

```
switch (time){
   case (12,"hours"): 
   break;
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Are there any other variables? Do you want to return "12 hours" if they enter 12? and "1 day" if they enter 24?

Comment: This feels like a classic case of "how do I make toast in a blender". It's just not what that tool is for. You use the `+` sign to add two integers, not a `switch` statement.

Comment: Your example has one integer, and syntax that is not java. Can you explain your issue a bit better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the operation inside the switch statement*

```java
switch( (hour_sum = (hour_x + hour_y)) / 24)
```

then is just about to check when is 0 or not

```java
 int hour_x=0;
 int hour_y=24;
 int hour_sum = 0;
 switch( (hour_sum = (hour_x + hour_y)) / 24) {
     case 0:
       return "hours";
       break;
     default:
       return "days";
 }
```

you can store total sum to use it in case you want to correct the return value

*Coding operations inside an 'if'/'switch' statement is not a good practice and should be avoided

Answer (score 2):

Since switch statements are meant for equality, this may not be the best application. If you only need to convert 24 hours to days and you have two time variables a and b then something like this should work (not tested):

```
int time = a + b;
string unit = "hours";
switch(time) {
    case 12: break;
    case 24: time = 1;
             unit = "day";
             break;
}
```

But this is very limited in it's capabilities. It might be better to use plain if-statements:

```
int time = a + b;
string unit;
if(time < 24) {
    unit = "hours";
} else {
    time = time / 24;
    if(time < 48) {
        unit = "day";
    } else {
        unit = "days";
    }
}
```